# Compiling ODE on windows without Visual Studio (for PyODE)

Tags: python, windows, dll, pyode

I'm new to compiling programs written by someone else, so I hope I'm not missing anything obvious.

What I am really trying to do is install PyODE, and I think I managed that just fine, but when running the PyODE examples I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python26\pyode-examples\tutorial3.py", line 12, in <module>
    import ode
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

which assume means that it can't find ODE installed. I thought PyODE came bundled with ODE but I guess not.. so now I'm trying to compile ODE according to these instructions:
http://opende.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Manual_%28Install_and_Use%29

but they all seem to revolve around creating configuration files for visual studio which I don't have.

Could someone please clue me in on the proper procedure here?
Thanks! :)
-Leav

Comment: did you try just installing the binaries (from http://pyode.sourceforge.net/#download)

Comment: yes I installed the binary package for PyODE, but I think you have to install ODE separately. am I correct?

Comment: "These packages have no external dependencies besides Python." That leaves little to the imagination. My guess is that the DLL is installed, but cannot be found. You could try copying it into the same directory as your Python script, see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

My Problem was completley unrelated to whether or not you could compile ODE without visual studio.

Simply copied ODE.dll which was in the python directory into the example's directory.

Thanks Thomas! :)